# Make chart width exclude x axis labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible in highcharts to make the chart width, the plotting area the same width whether there are labels or not?

For example, both these charts have width 150 but one looks thinner than the other because it has the labels enabled.

[image]

I can do this programmatically but it is a bit messy. Is there a way?. I tried, for example, to set the label as enabled but not visible but this combination of options does not exist.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you want to disable the `label` for the second graph?

Comment: No, I want to keep it - this is where the problem is I think..

Answer (score 0):

You can set fixed chart margin:

```
chart: {
    marginBottom: 20
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/st8c0r1p/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginBottom